# Is Node and express a good server-side package for a webgl application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, three.js, webgl

I am developing a webgl application. I am confused in choosing the right server-side technology to use for the application. I an using mongoDB as my database and three.js as my webgl library to ease the development.

Comment: Choosing a language is depend on multiple factor, You should consider project scale, budget, deadline and more. But in general, Node.js fits MongoDB well and maybe can be a good choice for your project.

Comment: WebGL will be heavy on the client, not the server. It doesn't really matter for the server whether you're doing WebGL or not.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of things to take into consideration.

first of all, what kind of connection do you need?
There are 3 ways of getting data from a server. Polling, long-polling, and a bidirectional connection.
Polling is the simplest. It's simply sending an AJAX call to a php or asp server, and the server replies. 
Long polling is a little more complex. It's sending a request to the server, and the server decides when to answer this call. This can also be done using a simple php/asp script.
A bidirectional connection is when things really become complicated and you need to use websockets. As far as i know neither php or asp support websockets so node.js, for me, is the only option here. Its setting up a connection between client and server so you can pass data back and forth. It doesnt rely on the client requesting data, the server can also decide to sent data to the client, which in turn can make something happen.

As for the databases, i also found mongoDB to work great with node.js, i tried it and havent even looked at SQL since then because quite frankly, i absolutely dispise SQL. So its just a matter of what your personal preference is.

And finally the webGL framework. It also depends on what you want and how complicated you want to make it. If you also need physics and/or collision detection (while three.js does have a small collision detection system) i'd take a look at babylon.js as well.